# Customerize ad placement in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to place banner ads in customized location in a mobile app created using Unity (for the Android platform)? I know one can in an Android-only app, you just need to create a layout, but in Unity, is it possible to attach a banner to a GameObject?

Comment: I don't think you can. Bcoz ad activity runs separately than the game activity. But you can choose the location and size easily with unity3d with the admob plugin.

Comment: @ImtiajAhmed Is it correct that Admob only allows ad location in a few discrete locations? I have an Unity Scroll Rect so like the ad to scroll around with other GameObjects. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah fixed locations if you are using https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-plugins/tree/master/unity but don't know about other plugins(paid/free). Maybe you can find some kind of flexible positions which you can simulate with your scrolling. Not sure though :(